JSDoc auto-generation in PhpStorm - no empty lines before parameters
Whenever auto-generating a JSDoc in PhpStorm, it adds an extra empty line before the parameters, presumably for description, however description is not needed all the time. I would like to set it so that it doesn't add it if possible.

Expected result:

    /**
     * @param param1
     * @param param2
     * @returns {*}
     */
    function exampleJSDocMethod(param1, param2) {
        /**
         * @type {number}
         */
        const exampleJSDocVar = 1;
    
        return param1 + param2 + exampleJSDocVar;
    }


Current result:

    /**
     *
     * @param param1
     * @param param2
     * @returns {*}
     */
    function exampleJSDocMethod(param1, param2) {
        /**
         *
         * @type {number}
         */
        const exampleJSDocVar = 1;
    
        return param1 + param2 + exampleJSDocVar;
    }

Is there a way to turn this off somewhere? Using PhpStorm's latest version (2024.1.4 at the time of writing this).
I've looked in the settings, if there is any option that can be changed and did a Google search for it as well, but did not find anything useful.

There is no such an option AFAIK. There is one for PHPDoc (PHP code) -- it has a dedicated File/Code Template for that. For JSDoc -- this is the most general ticket I could find with my quick search: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-13992
